# Как исправить заторможенную смену фрагментов в ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В моём приложении я сделал смену фрагментов с использованием `ViewPager`, но она почему-то сильно тормозит и на эмуляторе, и на телефоне(не из-за слабого железа). В чём может быть проблема? Код прикрепляю ниже:

`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Context context = getApplicationContext();
        //context.deleteDatabase("schoolsDB.db");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

`WelcomeActivity`

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private int scrollLimit;
    private Button nextPageBtn;
    private Button prevPageBtn;

    private void init(){
        fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager);
        viewPager=findViewById(R.id.welcome_viewpager);
        nextPageBtn =findViewById(R.id.welcome_next_btn);
        prevPageBtn =findViewById(R.id.welcome_prev_btn);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(){
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new WelcomeFragmentOne());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new WelcomeFragmentTwo());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    }

    void nextPage(int currentPage){
        if(currentPage<scrollLimit) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage + 1);
        }
    }

    void prevPage(int currentPage){
        if(currentPage>0){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage-1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        init();
        setupViewPager();

        prevPageBtn.setEnabled(false);
        scrollLimit = viewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if(position+1== scrollLimit){
                    nextPageBtn.setEnabled(false);
                }else{
                    nextPageBtn.setEnabled(true);
                }

                if(position==0){
                    prevPageBtn.setEnabled(false);
                }else{
                    prevPageBtn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        });


        Button.OnClickListener nextPageListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nextPage(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            }
        };

        Button.OnClickListener prevPageListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                prevPage(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            }
        };

        nextPageBtn.setOnClickListener(nextPageListener);
        prevPageBtn.setOnClickListener(prevPageListener);

    }
}
```

`ViewPagerAdapter`

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment){
        fragments.add(fragment);
    }
}
```

**UPD**: Добавил код фрагментов и их разметку.

`WelcomeFragmentOne`

```
public class WelcomeFragmentOne extends Fragment {

        public WelcomeFragmentOne(){

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wlcm1greeting, container, false);
            Log.d("Fragment One:", "Created!");
            return view;
        }
    }
```

`WelcomFragmentOne_(разметка)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/firstColor"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="235dp"
        android:src="@drawable/school"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`WelcomeFragmentTwo`

```
public class WelcomeFragmentTwo extends Fragment {

    private EditText login;
    private EditText password;
    private Button enterBtn;
    private Button registerBtn;

    public WelcomeFragmentTwo(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wlcm2login, container, false);
        login=view.findViewById(R.id.wlcm2login_edit_text_login);
        password=view.findViewById(R.id.wlcm2login_edit_text_password);
        enterBtn=view.findViewById(R.id.wlcm2login_button_confirm);
        registerBtn=view.findViewById(R.id.wlcm2login_button_registration);

        enterBtn.setEnabled(false);
        TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(login.getText().length()!=0 && password.getText().length()!=0){
                    enterBtn.setEnabled(true);
                }else{
                    enterBtn.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        };
        login.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        password.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

        registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), RegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

`WelcomeFrafgmentTwo_(разметка)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/firstColor"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="28dp"
        android:text="@string/log_in_invite"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/wlcm2login_edit_text_login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Логин"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/wlcm2login_edit_text_password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Пароль"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wlcm2login_edit_text_login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/wlcm2login_button_confirm"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="Войти"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wlcm2login_edit_text_password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/wlcm2login_button_registration"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="Зарегистрироваться"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wlcm2login_button_confirm" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: В приведённом коде проблем нет. Они во фрагментах. У вас, видимо, там сложный интерфейс и он долго отрисовывается. Покажите код и разметку фрагментов.

Comment: Добавил код фрагментов и их разметки.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, проблему решил! Оказалось, что изображение в 1м фрагменте было слишком большим, и уменьшив его разрешение качество осталось прежним, а тормоза прошли. Вернусь домой - сделаю полноценный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что разрешение изображения было слишком большим. Решил уменьшением изображения в коде фрагмента с помощью библиотеки `Picasso`(хотя можно и без неё, надо просто установить разрешение поменьше).

```
public class WelcomeFragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private ImageView imgView;

    public WelcomeFragmentOne(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wlcm1greeting, container, false);          
        imgView=view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        //Решение
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.school).resize(640, 640).into(imgView);
        return view;
    }
}
```